# Assuming God is real, can the level of joy we desire exceed the amount He desires/can create?

Tags: christianity

Can we, in our best attempts, desire for a level of happiness above what an infinite God can provide us with in Heaven?

Comment: I don't think this is the right site for this, but no, it doesn't follow, because you as a mortal are prone to error and therefore can imagine things that are not actually possible without noticing your mistake.  So you may imagine more joy/whatever than God could provide, or you may imagine it differently than God would intend it.  (Also, if God turns out not to be a logically coherent concept as you've stated it, "assume true = false" lets you prove pretty much everything....)

Comment: I thinking your missing what I mean (maybe I didn't explain well)...there is an inexpressable desire in some people, attatched to NO certain object. Obviously we might well fall in our efforts to imagine what this desire is for. I am talking about LEVELS of desire. I think it would contradict Christian ideas of God if one were to think that a mortal can desire more joy than God can provide. it almost states that we have a greater capacity than the infinite Himself!

Comment: @Rex Kerr It's also important to point out that I am talking about the joy God can give us when we see Him in Heaven. Not now (that, indeed, might be a nonesense question as we don't know the ins and outs of our life now...I assume, if God is real, however, that our ultimate destiney is joyous and loving (God in the Bible is Love and brings joy).

Answer (score 2):

In our imagination we have constructed numbers larger than all the atoms in the universe, and larger than in any concievable universe.

Words such as bliss, the ineffable & sublime reflect different aspects of transcendence.

Though one can say that we may be mistaken in our intuitions and our intimations - the Descartian doubt - it is also our sensibility that at root makes sense of the world and of words. Doubt obstinately and analytically defiant leads to the realm of solipsism - a cul-de-sac of thought. Doubt of that kind is the intellect introspecting. Sensibility cannot doubt as its the ground of our being.  Rather, with Heidegger one should have the world ready-at-hand; the world within and without. The sensual impact of the world without on our sensibility conditions our becoming as do the intimitations from the world within - they are at-hand.

The Good & the Beautiful - in their proper sense - and not as kitsch - as Plato knew it - is a reflection of the ineffable divine order in us.

In many religous traditions a correspondance is created between the divine realm and the human realm. Prometheus stole the fire of the gods - the divine spark - that illumines spirit.

Tagore, the Bengali poet & intellectual wrote:

> Thous hast made me endless, such is thy pleasure. This frail
>
> vessel thou emptiest again and again, and fillest ever with fresh life
>
> This little flute of a reed thou hast carried over hills and dales,
>
> ...
>
> Thy infinite gifts come to me only on these small hands of mine
>
> Ages pass, and still thy pourest, and still there is room to fill.

Tagore reflects on the possibility of infinite feeling and transcendence. In (one aspect) of the Hindu tradition one dissolves into the god-head (Brahman). In this poetic fragment he's using an image that opens Rumis Masnavi, the sufi Islamic treatise and acknowledging an affinity between these two very different traditions at some level.

So, yes; because the imagination and sensibility is more capacious than we can say. Wittgenstein made a distinction between show & say. We know much more than can be said. We have seen much more than can be said - and I do not mean here by this the instrumental power of the eye - take it, perhaps as the eye of the imagination - which identifies both inner & outer forms of sensibility. Then what is revealed to us - cannot be said - but it has been shown.

As to whether, we can imagine a *greater* joy/bliss/desire - I'm not sure that the logical nature of greater obtains in such discourse as this. Its the *existence* of intimations of such that I'm answering here.

Answer (score 1):

The element of free will is something u dd not factor in your hypothesis. 
The God did not create robots, so the choice that one makes determines the level of joy/happiness

Comment: But I mean, at our upmost ability are we able to desire more joy than the Lord can provide?

Comment: Your question is self contradictory in light of free-will. Or maybe i just dont understand your question.

Comment: I don't mean do all humans automatically recieve the an amount of desire for some level of happiness above what God can give us?- I mean can we, in our best attempts, desire for a level of happiness above what God can provide us in Heaven?

Answer (score -1):

If you have Jesus in your Heart, then you have the Holy Spirit, which a fruit comprises of joy.
Galatians 5:22 - 5:23

When you constantly communicate with God in your head & spirit, You achieve complete happiness.  Similar to the effects of the drug "ecstasy" (MDMA).

According to being happier than you will be in Heaven, I would have to say no.